# How to get Thunderbird to scan all mail, add all addresses as contacts?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I've set up Thunderbird, but have an empty address book. Is there some way to get Thunderbird to scan all my emails and add all the addresses it finds as contacts automatically?

edit: alternatively I am happy to export my contacts from Protonmail and then import to Thunderbird. However when I do this, Protonmail gives me a .vcf, and when I import it it just generates a list of approx 200 empty contacts. Useless!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up exporting as .vcf from protonmail. When I imported to Thunderbird it was completely broken and just resulted in a long list of 200 empty/blank contacts. To solve this i found an online .vcf to .csv converter and then imported the contacts as .csv. This worked splendidly.

Comment: Please elaborate. This answer is as currently written of no use to other users.